Why boundary terms goes to zero in Fourier Transforms derivatives?
The proof of the derivative is based on integration by parts:
$$\int_{-\infty}^{\infty} f^{\prime}(x) e^{-i k x} \mathrm{~d} x=\left.f(x) e^{-i k x}\right|_{-\infty} ^{\infty}+i k \int_{-\infty}^{\infty} f(x) e^{-i k x} \mathrm{~d} x=i k F(k)$$
where the boundary terms are zero provided $\lim _{x \rightarrow \pm \infty} f(x)=0$ (true for test functions). How can I show that this limit goes to zero?

What sort of functions are you working with? You typically assume that $f$ satisfies some sort of decay estimates before defining the Fourier transform.

Assuming $\lim _{x \rightarrow \pm \infty} f(x)=0$, which as you stated holds for the class of functions you might want to use in this settings like test functions,
$$\left.f(x) e^{-i k x}\right|_{-\infty} ^{\infty}= \lim_{x\to\infty}f(x)e^{-ikx}- \lim_{x\to-\infty}f(x)e^{-ikx}$$
Since $|e^{-ikx}|=1$, the $f(x)$ dominates in the limit, and we get
$$\lim_{x\to\infty}f(x)e^{-ikx} = \lim_{x\to-\infty}f(x)e^{-ikx}=0$$
which gives the equality you were looking for
$$
\left.f(x) e^{-i k x}\right|_{-\infty} ^{\infty}+i k \int_{-\infty}^{\infty} f(x) e^{-i k x} \mathrm{~d} x=i k F(k).
$$
